# How can I load checkboxes with dynamic names in a listbox, the names are populated from an XML having a <NAME> tag

Tags: c#, xml, wpf, checkedlistbox

I have the following XML,

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<TEST>
<Name>TESTRUN</Name>
<SyncByte>ff</SyncByte>
<SOM>53</SOM>
<PDADD>7e</PDADD>
<LENLSB>08</LENLSB>
</TEST>
```

I have defined a listbox in WPF and have simply added a single checkbox inside it hoping that it can manage the checkboxes dynamically. The requirement is that, I can have multiple XMLs like the one above but with different  tag in them. I need to load the ListBox with the value of the  tag from each XML, as a checkbox.

Design:
[image: Design of CheckedListBox from XML]

Comment: Why has no one mentioned the [XmlDataProvider Class](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.data.xmldataprovider(v=vs.110).aspx).

Comment: You are working with WPF, so think MVVM ! XML->Data->ViewModel->View

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As first you need to create a TEST class

```
public class TEST
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string PDADD { get; set; }
}
```

You can load the XML file with the XML serializer:

```
TEST obj;
XmlSerializer xs = new XmlSerializer(typeof(TEST));
using (XmlReader xr = XmlReader.Create("yourxmlfile.xml"))
{
    obj = (TEST)xs.Deserialize(xr);
}
```

After that, attach `obj` to the `DataSource` of your Checkbox-List and use `DataBind()` of it finally. The markup of the Checkbox-List should set the desired `DataValueField` and `DataTextField` to "Name" (property `Name` of TEST). Can your XML contain duplicated item names, you have to provide any ID in your XML, too. In that case, set `DataValueField` to "ID".

Also I suggest you to follow the standards for upper and lowercase in your names. So change "TEST" to "Test" and "PDADD" to "PDAdd".

Answer (score 0):

WPF way would be:

1. Create Test model class, which implements INotifyPropertyChanged interface and has IsSelected and Name properties
2. Load all xmls in the collection of that model class
3. Bind collection to ListBox
4. Create DataTemplate for ListBox's items. DataTemplate should contain checkbox and textblock controls and define bindings: CheckBox - to IsSelected property, TextBlock - to Name property

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
   <ListBox ItemsSource="{Binding Xmls}" Margin="2">
        <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
            <DataTemplate>
                <StackPanel>
                    <CheckBox Content="{Binding XPath=/TEST, Path=Name}"/>
                </StackPanel>
            </DataTemplate>
        </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
    </ListBox>
```

> ViewModel

```
    public class ViewModel1
{
    public ObservableCollection<XmlDataProvider> Xmls { get; set; }

    public ViewModel1()
    {
        Xmls = new ObservableCollection<XmlDataProvider>();
        Xmls.Add(GetXml());
        Xmls.Add(GetXml());
    }

    XmlDataProvider GetXml()
    {
        XmlDataProvider dataProvider = new XmlDataProvider();
        XmlDocument doc=new XmlDocument();
        doc.LoadXml(@"<TEST><Name>TESTRUN</Name><SyncByte>ff</SyncByte><SOM>53</SOM><PDADD>7e</PDADD><LENLSB>08</LENLSB></TEST>");
        dataProvider.Document = doc;
        return dataProvider;
    }
}
```

Answer (score -1):

Considering that you have been able to show `Checkbox` as an `Item` in your `ListBox`
There are a bunch of things you will have to do. The algorithm will look like..

```
foreach( var xml in YourXMLFilePathsList)
{
    //1. Read the contents of the xml file. Should be simple enough.

    //2. Deserialze the contents to an `object`. Look into XML serialization/deserialization

    //3. Insert this object in to the List that you will be setting as ItemsSource to your ListBox
}
```